# Understanding the motivation for redux-thunk

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Without redux-thunk, your action creators can still take dispatch as an argument and seemingly do whatever a thunk would:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892505/378622

So what's the motivation for redux-thunk, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Dan Abramov's answer here [How to dispatch a Redux action with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559) explains it in detail.

This summary is probably not complete, but my take from it is:

- No need to have dispatch as a prop in components and passing it around
- Async control flow is more convenient, you can treat other actions like promises without having to wrap them in `new Promise()` yourself
- Additional argument `getState` in actions to read from state